# How do I open up the web.py server to the web?

Tags: python, web.py

I would like people on the web to be able to enter something into the address bar of their browser and use the web.py app I have written. I have it working properly when I type localhost:8080/app but I want other people to be able to use it, with my home computer acting as the server. I know this must be an obvious question (the package is called web.py, after all), but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what steps to take to make that happen. I guess the link would need to be to my IP address, rather than a URL? Do I need to configure my router somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find your external IP google("what is my IP")

[image]

Second you need to set up a port forward on your router to redirect traffic from an external port to an internal port.

[image]

After the port forwarding is complete you should be able to navigate to `http://<your external ip>:<port>/`

Comment: FIRST you need to make your web app bomb-proof against internet attackers that might gain access to your server/network and the data there, or install viruses/trojans/crud. ONLY then should you do the steps above.

Comment: In addition, in order to find out how to forward ports on any router, there are very useful websites out there like http://portforward.com/. But of course, you shouldn't do this unless you're sure that your machine and server are secure - that is, if you plan on sharing your site publicly. In that case, a hosting solution would be a much better idea anyway.

Comment: It's asking for the following: External IP Address & Start/End Port, Local IP Address & Start/End Port, Protocol. I assume the end port is 8080, and the start port is 80, and that those should be local, but I'm not sure what the other values should be. I ran ipconfig to get my ip address, so is that external? It looks like an IPv6 address. the protocol I guess is TCP?

Comment: `ipconfig` will give you your internal ip.  `end port` should be the port that your python script is hosting on. `start port` should be whatever port you would like to host on externally ... it does not have to be port 80 ... that is just the default HTTP port.

Comment: In the end, the "external IP" turned out to be 0.0.0.0 (this means let anyone from any IP access it), the local IP was the 192.168.0.10 my router assigned to my machine, the start port and end port are both set to 8080, and the address someone needs to type in is the external IP address that google answered with, followed by:8080, folowed by the /app address.

Comment: @DouglasSummersStay `0.0.0.0` would be the hosting address defined in the Python script itself and possible within the router ... this is different than the `external address` which would either be used directly `you give it to a friend to check out your page` or indirectly `setup A records with Dyndns to link it to a host name such as mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up port forwarding on your router: Configure it so port 80 of your router forwards to port 8080 of your computer. (You can find your computers internal IP-address in your operating systems network config) You might also need to set your computer to use a static IP-address and disable DHCP.

Then other users will be able to access your server via your routers external IP-address. You can find out your external IP [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/). You might also want to set up a Dynamic DNS address so others can still access the server when your external IP-address changes. An example of such a service is [noip](http://www.noip.com/free)

As long as you're just doing some basic testing using your own computer is good enough but once you're running a real web service you should consider using a paid external webhosting service to improve security, reliability and performance.